# In IEnumerable extensions - why is only Count() optimized for ICollection?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

After de-compiling the Linq `IEnumerable` extension methods I was glad to see that
the `Count()` method, prior to trying to iterate the whole enumerable, attempts to downcast it to an `ICollection` or an `ICollection<T>` e.g:

```cs
    public static int Count<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) {

        if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");

        ICollection<TSource> collectionoft = source as ICollection<TSource>;

        if (collectionoft != null) return collectionoft.Count;

        ICollection collection = source as ICollection;

        if (collection != null) return collection.Count;

        int count = 0;

        using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator()) {
            checked {
                while (e.MoveNext()) count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Why isn't this happening in `Any()`? won't it benefit from using `.Count > 0` instead of creating an array enumerator?

Comment: If source is `Collection`, I belive that `MoveNext` (used in `Any`implementation only once in `if`) is as fast as downcasting to `Collection` and checking `Count`.

Comment: An `ICollection`'s count method *may* be faster than the naive approach that the above `Count` method falls back to - but it may, in fact (e.g. a linked list that doesn't store a count) actually have to walk the entire data structure to produce a count. So your suggested optimization could be a pessimization versus just accessing the first element in the collection.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever At first, I thought to give `LinkedList` as a example in my answer, later I realized that `LinkedList.Count` is O(1) only.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - *that* linked list's count is O(1). Anyone is free to implement any data structure they choose to and mark it as an `ICollection` and I thought a linked list that doesn't store a separate count would be one that most people could relate to. Once I saw your answer (which is making much the same point as my comment) I did +1 it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not all collections provide O(1) access for `Count` property. For example accessing count property of [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267339%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is O(n). So that optimization will make it worse and hence 
shouldn't be called as optimization.

Not only `ConcurrentQueue<T>`, Almost all concurrent collections (`ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue>`, `ConcurrentStack<T>` etc) falls in this category

May be that is why they decided not to do it.

Comment: Downvote because the answer didn't make sense. You can definitely improve the performance of Any() method when you cast the input to List<T> and check the "List<T>.Count > 0" condition, as already done in Count() method.

Comment: @ChrisEelmaa - there's no cast to `List<T>` here - there are casts to *interfaces* that already implement members that *exactly* match the semantics being sought after. Having the extension method only work with concrete types within the BCL would have a bit of a smell to it.

Comment: @ChrisEelmaa Don't be dense. My answer does makes sense. Your comment only doesn't makes sense. Question is about why optimization added with `ICollection` in `Count` method is not added for `Any`. Ok you said `List<T>`. What about `Array`?, What about `ObservableCollection`? and et all collections? You want to add if statements for each of them? Optimizations should be added as generic not for some specific concrete types.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, my bad, I mean't `IList<T>`. Some of the LINQ methods use `IList<T>`, such as First(), Last(), etc.. There's definitely very nice boost in Any() now(see my post). Why is that optimization not included? The answer is the same as "why are there many useful things missing from the .NET framework?"

Comment: @ChrisEelmaa That optimization is not adding a huge value as only very very very few classes implement `IList<T>`.

Comment: @ChrisEelmaa `Any`, unlike `Count`, is *already* O(1) *without* the optimization.  `Count` has very large potential gains from applying the optimization, `Any` has almost nothing to gain.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, if that were the case, LINQ team wouldn't have implemented the EXACT same logic I just implemented in First(), FirstOrDefault(), Single(), Last(), LastOrDefault, etc..

Comment: @ChrisEelmaa You should understand in those cases story is different. You need to access a indexer. `ICollection<T>` doesn't provide indexer, that's why they used `IList<T>`. But here you don't need a indexer so `IList<T>` is not used. [No client should be forced to depend on methods it does not use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle). If you need `Count` you should only depend on interface which provides `Count`. Nothing more. Got my point?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, okay, I'll upvote. What you're saying, definitely makes sense(I am not bi-polar :p), it's just the last question "Why isn't this happening in Any()? Won't it benefit from .Count() > 0", which my answer would be:  "Yes it will, but you need to use `IList<T>` instead of `ICollection<T>` as stated for few reasons. The optimization will work only for `IList<T>`, but it's better than nothing."

Comment: @ChrisEelmaa Start counting how many classes implement `IList<T>`. You'll come to know why they didn't do it. You can't even use all of your fingers.!

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, Servy: thanks for interesting discussion. I just realized what I said made no sense ultimately, as you can't really apply the optimization, whenever it's `IList<T>` or `ICollection<T>`, for the same reasons as Sriram has stated. There's no reason why `IList<T>`.Count() has to be O(1). ps, I am not sure about the last claim :p, `IList<T>` is definitely more popular guy than `ICollection<T>` in my books. http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/ilist.cs#b19f71a84062554b#references  79 implementations vs 63 implementations.

Comment: @ChrisEelmaa So if you agree with me consider removing the downvote

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, not sure how though. I tried before, but it says I can't remove unless it's edited. Guess they don't have anything against "rushed too fast to judge"?

Comment: @ChrisEelmaa Yes, I usually edit the post myself when I wanted to swap the vote. Now you can. I edited my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Nope. The cost of the code would always be bigger than any possible performance gains, which are pretty much nil. Don't forget that the whole point of LINQ is to chain a bunch of expressions like that, so you're most likely using `Any` either with a predicate, or with it's own bunch of filters etc. before that.

What's the case where you'd use `Any` as an alternative to `Count`? Even the `Count` optimization has very slim usage IMO - if you're doing `Count()` inside some logic that expects `IEnumerable` as a parameter, you're probably doing it wrong - at the very least, you'd tend to enumerate the enumerable multiple times, which is quite likely to break something or kill your performance :D

Don't forget that once you do *anything* on that enumerable-of-array, you've lost the "array-ness", e.g. `categories.Where(i => i.Name.StartsWith("Hello")).Count()` will *not* use the short-cut.

And of course, the cost of an enumerator on any empty enumerable will likely be pretty much free. The enumerator is just a simple struct, and on an array, there will not be any expensive initialization either.

Comment: I wasn't using it as an alternative to `Count()`, sometimes I use it to be more expressive.
As in, `array.Any()` is more readable than `array.Length > 0`

Comment: @Nitzankin Yes, but as soon as it's "more expressive", it no longer can do the simple `return Count > 0`.

Comment: Yes it can, with trying to downcast to ICollection, but then, as @SriramSakthivel stated, things get unpredictable and not always optimized

Comment: @Nitzankin You might be interested that when I've tried it in a simple benchmark, `Any()` was about twice as fast as `Count()`, even on an array - of course, the difference isn't really important anyway, since it can do either millions of times per second. Which is the reason why you shouldn't *guess* at performance, but **test** it instead. So keep using `Any` when you mean `Any` - unless you can prove that `Count` is actually measurably faster for your use case.

Comment: @Luaan: "What's the case where you'd use Any as an alternative to Count?" - if you want to know if there's any elements in the `IEnumerable<T>`. `Count()>0` will suffer O(n) on some cases(ConcurrentQueue for example). Prefer Any() my friends, it's there for a reason :-)

Comment: @ChrisEelmaa You missed my point. That's not an alternative use, that's a *different use*. I wasn't advocating the use of `Count` over `Any`, rather the opposite. But I agree that my wording is extremely ambiguous, or even outright misleading, sorry :D